# Python: navigate to directory, and insert command line on cmd window inside Python

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, cmd, mongoimport

I've read the documentations that other stackoverflow posts provided, but I couldn't understand what they are saying.

Here is what I want to achieve: I want to navigate to a specific directory that contains a specific executable file, and insert a command line.

So,

```
.\> cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin> mongoimport -h <IP_ADDRESS> -d <DB> -c <COLLECTION> -u <USER> -p <PASSWORD> --drop --file C:\data.txt
```

I need a code will perform  the two lines of code above inside Python. 
In .\3.4\bin directory, there is an executable file called 'mongoimport.exe'. And on the SAME LINE, I need to insert additional sentences to specify the external server I want to access.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `subprocess` like:

```
from subprocess import run

run(["C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\3.4\\bin\\mongoimport.exe",  "-h", "<IP_ADDRESS>", "-d", "<DB>", "-c", "<COLLECTION>", "-u", "<USER>", "-p", "<PASSWORD>", "--drop", "--file", "C:\data.txt" ])
```

It will execute only exe file, if for example you need execute a python file add the executable:

```
run(["python.exe", "your_python_file"])
```

[More information](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

Comment: Plus with the `cwd` kwarg (same as in `subprocess.Popen`), you can tell it to do all that inside `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin`. But I don't know if that's even necessary for your task.